# The usage of 'half out'

Tags: meaning, grammar

I'm reading a book and I've got a problem with the following sentence:

> Her door crushed open, the woman half out into the street.

How to interpret the second part of the sentence? Does it means *half out* is used as a verb ?

Comment: It simply means she was laying "over" the door way .. half of her bod is out  the door, and half inside. that's it - it's simple.  Say you're getting in a car .. and the person starts moving off.  It's common to yell, "hang on!  I'm only half-way in!" or "I'm still half-out!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem. You can't find a verb in the sentence and think "half out" might be it? Well, perhaps the naughty author ***might have written a sentence without a verb!***
"Crushed open" is adjectival (her door was crushed open) and "half out" is the same (the woman was half out of the car). So, no verb in the sentence to get in the way of that one, precise and instant image. Without action there is no time. The picture is frozen.

D'you think?

Answer (score 2):

"half out" is a compound or phrasal adjective. It means that she is only partially, as opposed to completely "out". "Out" could mean a few things here, but judging by the context provided, it sounds like the woman is physically outside of something (partially,) perhaps after a car crash part of the woman's body remains inside of the car while the other part is now outside of the car and sprawled out on the street.